# Listado tipo carrito de compras en PHP y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, lista

Estoy trabajando en un listado donde el usuario vaya agregando articulos a la lista tipo carrito de compras, es lo que se me ocurre para poder explicarlo mejor, se puede buscar y agregar articulos y sus detalles (clave, descripcion, cantidad y costo) pero cuando quiero agregar otro, lo que hace es que sustituye la información del articulo anterior.

```
    <table border=7 ALIGN=CENTER width="100%" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<tr align=center>
    <td>
        <font size="3">CLAVE</font>
    </td> 
    <td>
        <font size="3">DESCRIPCION</font>
    </td> 
    <td>
        <font size="3">COSTO</font>
    </td>

<?php
if ($_SESSION[cont1]=="0"){
?>
    <td colspan="2">
        <font size="3">CANTIDAD</font>
    </td>

<?php
}else{
echo '2',$_SESSION[cont1];
?>
    <td>
        <font size="3">CANTIDAD</font>
    </td> 

    <td>
        <font size="3"></font>
    </td> 
<?php
}   
?>
</tr>                                                                          

<?php
echo '<br>Contador SESSION: ',$_SESSION[cont1];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

$desc1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["desc1"]);

$res1 = $mysqli->XXXXX

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1)) {


$cont1=$cont1+1;
$_SESSION[cont1]=$_SESSION[cont1]+1;


$m=$_SESSION[cont1];

$r = array($registro['clv'],$registro['desc1'],$registro['cost1'],$registro['cant1']); 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION[$m] = $r;

echo "<br>Primer valor: ".$_SESSION[$m][0];
echo "<br>Segundo valor: ".$_SESSION[$m][1];  
echo "<br>Tercer valor: ".$_SESSION[$m][2];
echo "<br>Tercer valor: ".$_SESSION[$m][3];  

$total1=$total1+$registro['cost1'];


?>
<tr align=center>
    <td>
        <font size="3"><?php echo $registro['clv'];   ?></font>
    </td> 

    <td>
        <font size="3"><?php echo $registro['desc1'];  ?></font>
    </td> 

    <td>
        <font size="3">$<?php echo $registro['cost1'];  ?></font>
    </td> 

    <td>
        <font size="3"><?php echo $registro['cant1'];  ?></font>
    </td> 
</tr>







<?php
}

if ($total1=="") {


    Echo '<center><h1><br> No Existe información para mostrar </h1></center>';
    }else{







$promedio=$total1/$_SESSION[cont1];

}

    ?>
<tr align=center>
    <td colspan="5">
        <font size="3">Costo Total de la Herramienta: <br>$<?php echo $total1;  ?></font>
    </td> 
</tr>



<?php


if ($desc1==""){
$cont1=0;
echo '<br>Contador es cero: ',$cont1;
}else{
echo '<br>Descripcion: ',$desc1;
echo '<br>Contador diferente de cero: ',$cont1;
}


}


?>






<br><br>

<form method="post" name="desc1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">


<TR ALIGN=CENTER> 
<TD colspan="5">
        <H3><label for="desc1">Seleccionar Herramienta para agregar: </label></H3>
<?php
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

?>   
<select name="desc1">    
    <?php    
    while ( $registro = $res1->fetch_array() )    
    {   
        ?>  

        <option value="<?php echo $registro['desc1']; ?>" >
        <?php echo $registro['desc1']; ?>
        </option><br>

        <?php

    }  
    ?> 



</select>



<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aceptar"><br>
<br><br>
</form>




<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit2']))

{

$_SESSION[cont1] = "0"; 

}
?>

<TR ALIGN=CENTER> 
<form method="post" name="desc1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<td ALIGN=CENTER>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Aceptar"><br>
<br><br>
</form>
</td>
</TR> 


</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca el código que tienes hasta el momento, para poder ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: subi la parte que me esta dando lata.

Answer (score 1):

En lo personal te recomiendo que no uses base de datos para hacer esto,
yo estoy en un proyecto similar y la verdad es que guardar el carrito de compras en una base de datos es desgaste de recursos en vano:
**la opcion que yo uso:**
puedes almacenar toda la informacion en una cookie con esta estructura:

> producto_id,cantidad,color,etc,etc;producto_id,cantidad,color,etc,etc;producto_id

donde separas por comas los datos, y por ; los items de tu carrito

y cuando quieras mostrar tu carrito haces esto:
consultas todos tus productos (MYSQL) y los almacenas en un array donde el indice del array sea el id de tus productos para cuando quieras obtener informacion del mismo solo lo llames asi:

> $mis_productos["id_producto_de_cookie"]["nombre"];

cosa que asi no estas consultando varias veces tu base de datos.

esta respuesta es liteal y logica, no te puse ningun codigo porque cada sistema es diferente y no tengo informacion de tu bd ni tu estructura php

Notas:

1. Para listar tus items de la cookie usas un explode (php), ejemplo: `$items_car = explode(";",$_COOKIE["carrito"]);` y con un preg_match filtas tu data y con un for recorres todos tus items del carrito y dentro del for le metes el `$mis_productos["id_producto_de_cookie"]["nombre"];`

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que crear una tabla llamada, por ejemplo, 'artículo_a_carrito' donde estarían las siguientes filas: id, id_articulo, id_usuario. De esta manera, cada vez que se agrega un artículo, se crea un nuevo artículo en la base de datos y se guarda toda la info que mencioné anteriormente. Obviamente, recomiendo absolutamente que cuando hagas el display de la lista de artículos disponibles, agregues un input type hidden con un value igual al número de id del artículo. Entonces, cuando lo incluyas en la tabla mencionada al comienzo de esta respuesta, le envías por ajax el valor del id_articulo a tu archivo php que hace las peticiones. Dentro de este php obtienes el id_articulo y obtienes el $_SESSION["id], y por último lo insertas (y en el caso que se sellecione "sacar artículo del carrito", se abriría otro php que lo elimina en vez de agregarlo. No hace falta poner los datos del artículo en el carrito, porque sería duplicar la info que ya estaría guardada donde el id_articulo es igual al id del artículo específico en tu tabla de artículos.

Espero que te haya podido ayudar. Si necesitas algún ejemplo, me avisas.

Comment: PD: No hace falta que subas ningún código en tu pregunta. Ya que en stackOverflow no se resuelve el problema haciendole el código al que pregunta, sino dando una orientación específica para solucionar el problema. De todos modos, si necesitas un ejemplo, encantado estaré.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad tiene mucho sentido lo que me comentas, lo voy a poner en practica, pero una pequeña consulta, como puedo hacer para que las filas las vaya incrementando conforme vaya agregando articulos, ya que me lleve toda la tarde intentando hacerlo y nada, muchas gracias nuevamente y disculpa la molestia.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Las filas se incrementan a medida que agregas artículos. A toda fila (independientemente de cual sea la tabla o su función) debes agregarle un identificador (id) y lo seteas como auto increment y pimary key (busca esas opciones en los select que tiene cada fila de la nueva tabla que crees manualmente en tu base de datos). Valga la redundancia, eso no se hace por php, sino antes de que crees la tabla (puedes agregarselo después de haber puesto otros campos).

Comment: A okas, voy a aplicarlo como me comentas, muchas gracias, saludos y bendiciones.

Comment: Por nada, suerte!